# How to put PHP(With Sql that read database) Code inside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am trying to draw a pie chart using JavaScript, The challenge here is I don't know how many slices the chart will have so, I have to read the chart values in the database. So, How do I put PHP code inside  **values: [10,12,78,15,45, 55],** to get the live values??

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            var data = [{
              values: [10,12,78,15,45, 55],
              labels: ['OK', 'NO','MAYBE', 'SOMETIMES','NEVER', 'I DONT KNOW'],
              type: 'pie'
            }];

            var layout = {
              height: 380,
              width: 480
            };

            

            Plotly.newPlot(graph, data, layout);


            </script>
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Numeric JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeric/1.2.6/numeric.min.js"> //Hosted Scripts



<div id="graph" style="width: 480px; height: 380px;"> </div>
```

Comment: use `XMLHttpRequest` (AJAX) to get live data

Comment: @Kazz I'm not familiar with AJAX and i need this ASAP

Comment: You could use PHP ECHO to put the variables in a javascript array, before the other script tag.